# Python3: Cannot import CSV Files into my Jupyter Notebook -- See Specific Error & Screenshot Below

Tags: python, file, import, jupyter-notebook, desktop

I have a train.csv file sitting on my Desktop that I want to import into my Jupyter notebook.

The file is located at the following place:

I tried the following Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df_train = pd.read_csv('C:\home\name\Desktop\train.csv')
```

But I got the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\home\pinzhi\Desktop\train.csv' does not exist: b'C:\home\pinzhi\Desktop\train.csv'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try raw prefix: `pd.read_csv(r'C:\home\pinzhi\Desktop\train.csv')`

Comment: `df_train = pd.read_csv('/home/pinzhi/Desktop/train.csv')` ?

Comment: @lostCode: thank you!!! is that the code for a linux path?

Comment: of course, you're welcome! @PineNuts0

Comment: why are you feeding a windows path if you're on linux in the first place?

Comment: I didn't know that was a windows path ... using linux for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use...

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('/home/pinzhi/Desktop/train.csv')
```

if you are using linux you must use path of linux.